# In python flask with mysql, can I use the same connection throught the app life cycle?

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Here is my python  flask code:

```
from flask import *
import mysql.connector
app = Flask(__name__)
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="<my db host>",
  user="<my db user>",
  password = "<my db password>",
  database = '<my db>'
)

@app.route('/posts/<int:post_id>')
def get_post(post_id):
  with conn.cursor(dictionary=True) as cur:
    cur.execute('select * from posts where ID=%s',(post_id,))
    result = cur.fetchone()
    ans=result['post_content']
    return ans
    

app.run(debug=False,threaded=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=80)
```

Note how I don't create a new connection for each request. Instead, I use the same connection for all requests.

My question is: is there any potential problems in this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the same connection, because it will stay open forever, only open an SQL connection when you need to use it, and close it afterward. Not doing so can lead to a lot of errors.